# remove bootstrap select focus outline in chrome

Tags: css

I tried to do the following to remove the focus on the select of bootstrap (i don't want to remove it actually, just to change it's color)

```
select:focus{
    color:#333333;
    //border:10px solid red;
    border:none!important;
    outline:none!important;
  }
```

still see a shadow around it...anyone have a clue?

Comment: You can use your browser's developer tools to inspect the element and you should be able to see which css rules are affecting it. Then override those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure (without a picture) that you'll need `box-shadow: none!important;` as well

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://www.bootply.com/L0Sju3iguY

set `outline:0` and `box-shadow:none`

```
select:focus{
 outline:0;
 box-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style could be overwritten by another style with !important. Without code sample it's a bit tricky to help you... Generally you should avoid using !important(if you are using it only to try to make this work it's OK). Are you using any classes on your input or something?