# Bootstrap-Select : remove ugly focus border

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I know this has been asked for regular html controls, but I cannot seem to get rid of this ugly black border that surrounds my selectpicker list box :

[image]

And when I don't have focus:

[image]

There's already a focus radius blue color that surrounds my input, so for accessibility, I do not need this black one. I've read everywhere that I need to use `outline: none;` css, but it isn't working in my case.

This is my CSS:

```
.customSelect{
  border: 1px solid #ced4da !important;
  color: #495057 !important;
}
.customSelect:hover{
  background-color: #f8f9fa !important;
}
.customSelect:focus{
  outline:none !important;

  /* also tried adding in :
  outline-width: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  */
```

And my input html:

```
<select name="function_title_id" 
id="function_title_id"  
title="Please select..."
class="form-control selectpicker" 
data-live-search="true"
data-style="customSelect"
data-dropup-auto="false"
disabled>
</select>
```

What am I missing ? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Here's a fiddle link showing my problem :
https://jsfiddle.net/jocxaqe9/

Comment: Your class does not match your css selector: ```.selectpicker```.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999996/remove-bootstrap-select-focus-outline-in-chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove bootstrap select focus outline in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999996/remove-bootstrap-select-focus-outline-in-chrome)

Comment: you are just wrong to get class

Comment: Still no go. I tried using the .selectpicker css selector, but it doesn't change anything. I've update my question with a fiddle link to demo my problem. P.s. the red color was just for testing.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution for this. It's a little "hack" but seems to work :

1. Need to define the following attributes to the select input:

   - data-style-base="form-control" *-- must also **keep** the form-control class!*
   - data-style="" *-- or any other custom class to apply*
2. Add the following CSS:

```
.bootstrap-select .form-control:focus {
    outline: 0px none #fff !important;
}

.bootstrap-select .form-control > div.filter-option:focus {
    outline: 0px none #fff !important;
}

.bootstrap-select .form-control > div.filter-option > div.filter-option-inner:focus {
    outline: 0px none #fff !important;
}

.bootstrap-select .form-control > div.filter-option > div.filter-option-inner > div.filter-option-inner-inner:focus {
    outline: 0px none #fff !important;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sak06om8/

Answer (score 4):

This works in 2022 for Bootstrap 5
Removes all focus shadows

```
*:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

just make sure this is below the bootstrap css file

Comment: you can also give class name and :focus if want to remove only one choosen one, not globally.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 5:

Add the class "`shadow-none`" to remove the shadow.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your CSS.

```css
.bootstrap-select button.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

See, the thing that the other answers didn't take into account is that this plugin adds it's own **button** inside a **div** with the class `bootstrap-select` and only uses the data inside **select** to build it's dropdown. Hence adding any style to your **select** tag would be useless and have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

`outline: none` and `box-shadow: none` are sufficient to do what you want, your CSS is correct but you are not applying it right, you need to add the class `customSelect` to the select so:

```
<select name="function_title_id" 
    id="function_title_id"  
    title="Please select..."
    class="form-control selectpicker customSelect" 
    data-live-search="true"
    data-style="customSelect"
    data-dropup-auto="false"
    disabled>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add correct selector in CSS.

```css
.selectpicker:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select name="function_title_id" 
id="function_title_id"  
title="Please select..."
class="form-control selectpicker" 
data-live-search="true"
data-style="customSelect"
data-dropup-auto="false">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just added an update with a fiddle showing my issue. I've tried using the .selectpicker selector, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

see the problem? `customSelect` is your `data-style`, your class is `selectpicker`. Just change `customSelect` with `selectpicker`

```
.customSelect{
  border: 1px solid #ced4da !important;
  color: #495057 !important;
}
.customSelect:hover{
  background-color: #f8f9fa !important;
}
.customSelect:focus{
  outline:none !important;

  /* also tried adding in :
  outline-width: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  */
```

```
<select name="function_title_id" 
        id="function_title_id"  
        title="Please select..."
        class="form-control selectpicker" 
        data-live-search="true"
        data-style="customSelect"
        data-dropup-auto="false"
</select>
```

Comment: Still no go. First, I thought data-style was applied on the button that is generated... Regardless, I tried using .selectpicker:focus{..} Added outline, box-shadow, etc to none or 0, nothing does it. I still get that black focus ... Somehting else by bootstrap that forces that outline ??